# prerequisite functionality for which validation for Circular dependency needed

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working on a training module where I need to add a prerequisite functionality for which everything is done except for the validation for Circular Dependency( for example training1 is required for 2 and 2 is required for 3 and 3 is required for 1).
till now I have wrote CTE which is doing the work partially but now the problem is I also have to retrieve the trainingIds and its PrerequisiteTrainingIds in table Format that are causing circular dependency.
My FIndings-

```
-- Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate data
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT
  [TrainingId],
  [RequiredTrainingId],
  1 AS [Level],
  CAST([TrainingId] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' + CAST([RequiredTrainingId] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [path]
 FROM [Training].[Prerequisite]
 WHERE [TrainingId] = @trainingId
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
  CTE.TrainingId,
  [e].[RequiredTrainingId],
  CTE.[Level] + 1,
  CTE.[path] + '.' + CAST([e].[RequiredTrainingId] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [path]
 FROM CTE
 INNER JOIN [Training].[Prerequisite] [e]
 ON CTE.RequiredTrainingId = [e].[TrainingId]
 WHERE CTE.[path] NOT LIKE '%' + CAST([e].[RequiredTrainingId] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '.%'
)
SELECT  top 1*
FROM CTE
WHERE [TrainingId] = @trainingId
AND [RequiredTrainingId] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [path] DESC
```

Comment: Debugging circular dependencies for recursive CTEs can be difficult. Why not test if a circular dependency is created during each `INSERT` of prerequisite and rollback the change if it happens, to proactively prevent that prerequisite from being added?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)